# run a batch file from TFS 2010 build

Tags: tfs, msbuild, permissions, build-automation

After a specific build, I want to run a batch file which has TF.exe commands which do the following:
Check out a DLL 
Copy one of the "freshly built dlls" over top of the checked out DLL,
then check it back in.

I tried setting up an InvokeProcess build activity to run the batch file, but it gets a permissions error when trying to execute the batch file.

I realize that I can and probably should do this with PowerShell, however, I dont want the headache of signing right now.
Any suggestions on doing this correctly?

Comment: What's the permission error you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably going to get doink for this answer, but you should not be checking in built DLLs into a source repository, as you cannot version them. There is no "delta" operation.

Having said that, there are a couple of ways I can think of that might at least get you in the direction you are looking at. A PostBuild step to copy is an option (NOTE: When you use this type of option, all user's will have to have the DLLs on the same relative location as you do, but you already have chewed off that bite most likely).

You will have to handle the check out and check in through another process, but services or PowerShell both might be an option (although you don't want the headache).

It has been some time, but working with some type of CI methodology could be another option to explore. MS now has CI available in TFS, but there are other options, like Cruise Control .NET.

Comment: You can version assemblies with http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/05/15/version-assemblies-with-tfs-2010-continuous-integration.aspx

Comment: Not exactly what I was focused on, although it is an interesting take on the issue of grabbing the right version. I was focused more on the fact that most businesses loading assemblies into their TFS repository are simply making a place to get latest. As you do not get deltas from compiled source, like source code, you end up with a lot of waste of space if all you are doing is storing latest.

Comment: While it's true that binary deltas are pretty useless, there is a school of thought that advocates putting pretty much everything under source control so you have one-stop shopping for everything related to a single published version.  It's not crazy and shouldn't necessarily be discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not understanding why you can't simply perform the operations in your batch file from MSBuild.  For example, items can be checked out, and in, from TFS by executing the TfsSource task from the [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com).

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by creating Custom Activities for Checkout and Checkin and use Invoke Process for Copy the Dll's. 
Check this link for Checkout, Checkin custom activities: http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/13/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-5-Increase-AssemblyVersion.aspx